# Python requests: how to handle status code 304

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use `requests` and `bs4` to get info from a website, but am receiving the status code 304 and no content from `request.get()`. I've done some reading and understand that this code indicates the resource is already in my cache. How can I either access the resource from my cache, or preferably, clear my cache so that I can receive the resource new?

I've tried adding the following header: `headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}` to `requests.get()` but still have the same issue.

Additionally I've looked into the `requests-cache` module, but am unclear on how or if this could be used to solve the problem.

code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://smsreceivefree.com/')

print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

output:

```
304
b''
```

Comment: I think they are sending you the response even though (according to the HTTP spec) they shouldn't: 304 is only sent when the request was conditional (i.e. had a `If-Modified-Since` header). Since you aren't sending this, it seems they just reply with that to "botty" user-agents like the one of requests.

Comment: @L3viathan That makes a lot more sense than what I was reading. I changed the user-agent and now everything works! If you post this as an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A server should send a **304 Not Modified** reply if the client sent a conditional request, like one having an `If-Modified-Since` header. This makes sense if the client already has a cached version of the page, and wants to avoid downloading the content *if* he already has the newest version of it.

In this case, the website seems to send a 304 to certain kinds of clients, as it seems: ones where the User-Agent seems to indicate automation (which is true, in your case).

The server should instead send a 4xx error code, probably a **403 Forbidden**, but likely uses a 304 in order to throw bot writers off the right track and make them come to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

If your request has a header, make sure to remove `'if-none-match'` (or similar) from the header:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    ...,
    'if-none-match': ..., # <- Remove this
    ...
}

response = requests.get(..., headers=headers)
response
```